# Passing DI object to constructor of new class

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, razor-pages, dbcontext

So, in Razor Pages I know how I can use Dependency Injection to inject my `DbContext` (for example) in the constructor to access it in the whole class by creating a global private `readonly` variable.

However, let's say I have a `DbManager` class that makes all the calls to the DB (to avoid making them from every Razor Page in the application), then I have to pass the context to that class, even though I'm using (at least to my knowledge) dependency injection there as well.

Shouldn't it be able to *find* it without actually passing it to the constructor, and isn't that the *whole point* of dependency injection, or am I missing something?

What is the best practice here? Just feels wrong to pass the context as a parameter! I suspect I'm doing something wrong... Am I?

```cs
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly AppDbContext _context;
    
        public IndexModel(AppDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
    
        public void OnGet()
        {
            var result = new DbManager(_context).GetStuffFromDb(); // Feels weird to pass the context as a parameter here!
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you are not making any explicit reference calls to the context then only inject the DbManager. The context will be injected into the manager provided it was also registered in the composition root

Comment: Prevent posting [images of code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) to Stack overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not making any explicit reference calls to the context within `IndexModel` then only inject the DbManager.

```cs
private readonly IDbManager manager;
    
public IndexModel(IDbManager manager) {
    this.manager = manager;
}
    
public void OnGet() {
    manager.GetStuffFromDb();
    
    //...
}
```

The context will be injected into the manager when being resolved, provided it (the context) was also registered in the composition root

```
//...

builder.Services.AddScoped<IDbManager, DbManager>();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(....);

//...
```

Reference [Explicit Dependencies Principle](https://deviq.com/explicit-dependencies-principle/)

Comment: Then I get an error "Unable to resolve service for type 'DiExample.Data.DbManager' while attempting to activate 'DiExample.Pages.IndexModel'."

Comment: Do you mean I have to put the DbManager into the DI container too? Because I did, and it works.

builder.Services.AddScoped<IDbManager, DbManager>();

Comment: In that case you have to inject the abstraction (ie: IDbManager). I'll update the answer to match the registration shown in your comment.